# Why OpenCV has only 6 extrinsic parameters in calibration function?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, extrinsic-parameters

I use the Opencv sample code to do the camera calibration. As far as I know, the extrinsic parameter have 12 elements but in the OpenCV the sum of rotation vector and translation vector is 6.

Why OpenCV has only 6 parameters ?

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/_downloads/camera_calibration.cpp

Comment: in line 525, it's say that "a set of 6-tuples"
cvWriteComment( *fs, "a set of 6-tuples (rotation vector + translation vector) for each view", 0 );

Comment: 3D rotation + 3D translation = 6 parameters.

Answer (score 2):

`calibratecamera` method
In calibrateCamera method output `rvecs` and `tvecs`, 3D vector for rotation([since any rotation matrix has just 3 degrees of freedom](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#rodrigues)) and translation. They use [`Rodrigues`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#rodrigues) method to convert 3x4 matrix `R` to 3D vector `r`. Thus, only 6 extrinsic parameters.